# GAE push to deploy when multiple devs

Tags: google-app-engine, staging

By deploy, I assume they mean code changes are pushed to production?

If I had 2 or three devs working with me on a project, what is to stop them from pushing changes that break the production site?

What checks and balances do we have to avoid such error? Do you setup a staging and production environment in GAE, having someone manually verify everything appears to work before making live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit individual devs doing uncontrolled pushes to the code.google.com (from which the deploys happen), then arrange for one and only one local repository be the local repo-of-record, and only configure that one to know about the source.google.com 'origin' server. Integrations are pulled into that repo, and (when you're ready) push to deploy from there.

Here's how it works under the covers. When you use `gcloud` to set up a project, it modifies `default/.git/config` to know about source.google.com, and to use an authentication helper that ties in to oauth (re-using the token that `gcloud auth login` will store locally) to authenticate. To limit deployment, make this the integration repo, and configure dev repos to push to it.

If you set up a separate staging version of the app, it's a policy decision on your side about whether to use the same scheme, or let developers deploy to staging individually. The mechanism you'd use to configure this is all `.git/config` wiring.